# Convert two arrays into single array of objects

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I have two arrays and need to convert these arrays into a single object array using jolt.

Input

```
"Name": ["Test  Test", "Test2  Test"]
"email": ["Test@tesasds.com", "Test2@test.com"]
```

output

```
[{"Name":"Test  Test","email":"Test@tesasds.com"},{"Name":"Test2  Test","email":"Test2@test.com"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description inline:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      // for every key
      "*": {
        // and every item in the array
        "*": {
          // create a structure <index of array> : key : value
          // This will therefore join the two because the indexes will be the same
          "@": "&.&2"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    //Remove the index as key
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]
```

I'd suggest running the first shift to get understanding of the description.